# UpdatePanel doesnt work as intended for file upload control

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I click on the attach button, It adds a new row to the grid with the postedFile name.
But its also causing the whole page to refresh, as if the updatePanel doesnt exist. Whereas, I would like just the gridview to update. Why does this have to be this way with file upload controls. The UpdatePanel works as desired for other controls/grids on page.

I do not have a knowledge on jquery, so have to work it out only with c#. Any suggestions.

```
<asp:updatepanel runat="server" updatemode="conditional">
 <triggers>
   <asp:postbacktrigger controlid="btnAttach"/>
 </triggers>
 <contenttemplate>
  <asp:gridview ...../>
  <asp:fileupload id="fup" runat="server">
  <asp:button id="btnAttach" text="attach" runat="server/>
 </contenttemplate>
</asp:updatepanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use the ajax asyncFileUploader

[Link](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/asyncfileupload/asyncfileupload.aspx)

[Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42865/AsyncFileUpload-Control-New-Control-in-Ajax-Contro)

it will help you without postback and without jquery
it use plain javascript and its easy the following link containing the example also

Answer (score 0):

Fileupload is one of the controls that is not compatible with updatepanel:

[Read here](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx)